# $R[x]/(x^2)\simeq R[x]/((x-1)^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How do I prove that $R[x]/(x^2)\simeq R[x]/((x-1)^2)$? I tried to use the universal property of quotient rings as follows. Consider the composition $$R[x]\rightarrow R[x]\rightarrow R[x]/((x-1)^2)$$ given by $x\mapsto x-1\mapsto x-1+(x-1)^2$. The first map is an isomorphism. The kernel of the second map is $(x-1)^2$. The kernel of the composition is therefore $(x-1)^2$. If an ideal $I$ in $R[x]$ lies in the kernel, then the composition factors through $R[x]/I$. But the ideal $(x^2)$ doesn't lie in the kernel, so I cannot apply this universal property. Is is the wrong track?

Comment: There is a ring automorphism of $R[x]$ such that $x\mapsto x-1$, that sends your ideal $(x^2)$ to $((x-1)^2)$. It then induces the isomorphism you want.

Comment: By using the universal property, I was trying to formalize the statement "it then induces the isomorphism".

Comment: In other words, my question is how exactly the automorphism $x\mapsto x-1$ induces the desired isomorphism?

Comment: The kernel of the composition is $(x^2)$, not $(x-1)^2$.  The kernel of $R[x] \to R[x]/(x-1)^2$ is $(x-1)^2$, and the inverse image of this under the automorphism $x \mapsto x-1$ (whose inverse is $x \mapsto x+1$) is $(x^2)$.

Comment: @Quasicoherent This makes sense, thanks! Now I can just use the first isomorphism theorem, without the universal property.